# Unable to override storybook preview panel?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, storybook

I found a way to override `.sb-show-main` by having a `storybook.scss` as below.

```css
//.storybook/storybook.scss

.sb-show-main {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Then simply import it into `.storybook/preview.js`

```js
import "./storybook.scss";
```

The problem I'm facing and couldn't understand is that, `background-color: green` do have effect, but `padding` & `margin` seems to be ignored. Wondering if anyone ever modifying `sb-show-main`?

The default value for padding is `1rem`, I would like to change it to `20px` instead.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using !important to force the rule?

Comment: @Bjorn.B: Indeed that solved my problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped! I'll add it as an answer in case people come looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles you are trying to overwrite may be using the css !important directive, or may be more specific in their targeting of an element. I always try to be specific first, but otherwise I will use `!important` as a last resort.

```css
.container header ul li p {
  color: blue;
}

// OVERWRITE STYLES 
p { /* this wont work, because it's not as specific as the original rule */
  color: yellow;
}

.container header h1 ul li p { /* try this first */
  color: purple;
}

p { /* otherwise use !important as last resort */
  color: orange !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Logo</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><p>One</p></li>
      <li><p>Two</p></li>
      <li><p>Three</p></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</div
```